# Retrieving twitter data based on location

Tags: twitter

Is there a free way to pull a Twitter stream particular to a location? I could not find anything like this in their api docs.

I found something from DataSift, but their prices are way too high for what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use twitter search...

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=techstars&geocode=40.1241,-102.2411,1mi

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets
Which requires authentication?

Comment: it requires some authentication, although it said somewhere that unauthenticated requests can be made; I'll investigate further... thanks for pointing me in the right direction